# Using BroadcastReceiver in job scheduler for detecting power savers

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-jobscheduler

How can I use BroadcastReceiver in jobScheduler? Since power saver filter of broadcast receiver is sent to registered receiver, declaring receiver in manifest is not working. Henceforth it should be registered inside the class. I tried it in the jobScheduler (Plz have a look at the code below) but it is not working.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (jobScheduler == null) {
            jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

            ComponentName jobService =
                    new ComponentName(getPackageName(), MyJobService.class.getName());

            JobInfo jobInfo
                    = new JobInfo.Builder(MYJOBID, jobService).setPeriodic(15 * 60 * 1000L)
                    .setExtras(bundle)
                    .setPersisted(true)
                    .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
                    .build();

            int jobId = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);

            if (jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo) > 0) {
            } else {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MyJobService.java

```
public class MyJobService extends JobService {

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        jobP = jobParameters;

    if (mLocationRequest == null) {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(100 * 1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(60 * 1000);
    }

    if (client == null) {
        client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        client.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                onLocationChanged(locationResult.getLastLocation());
            }
            @Override
            public void onLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability locationAvailability) {
            }
        },
        Looper.myLooper());
    }
    if (powerSaverChangeReceiver == null) {
        powerSaverChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.e("powerSaver", "powerSaver");
            }
        };
    }

    if (filter == null) {
        filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.os.action.POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED");
        registerReceiver(powerSaverChangeReceiver, filter);
    }
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
    Log.e("onStopJob", "onStopJob");//for debug
    if (ul != null) {
        ul.cancel(true);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(powerSaverChangeReceiver);
}
}
```

Comment: got any solution yet?